# Spanned string loses bold style when adding characters

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, spannablestring, spanned

I set the following text and style in my `EditText`:

```
SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder();

sb.append("Hello");
sb.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 5, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
sb.append("World Test");
et.setText(sb);
```

The result is this: "**Hello**World Test". This is fine. Now when I position the cursor after the "d" character (i.e. before the space that separates `World` and `Test`) and enter a character, the **Hello** automatically loses its bold style.

Why is that? That is confusing me. It only happens when positioning the cursor directly after the "d" in `World` and entering a character. For all other cursor positions it works as expected.

Why is that and how to fix it? I want **Hello** to stay in bold.

Comment: when you manually edit the editText the text is replaced, that's why. You need to implement a text watcher on the textview, and manually re-set the bold style to the part you need

Comment: But why does it lose the formatting *only* when I position the cursor after the "d" character? With all other cursor positions, the formatting stays in place. It's only this single cursor position which causes the formatting getting lost.

Comment: try adding a textWatcher and look at which callbacks are called

Comment: Ok, by examining the callback parameters I can see that when the cursor is at the problematic position a whole range of characters is replaced whereas at other positions only a single character is replaced. Then the behaviour makes sense then. But it's really frustrating to see that I have to re-apply styles manually. There should really have been a way to let `EditText` do that automatically.

Comment: I agree with you, I also expected that to be the "default" behavior, glad you find out a solution, can you post it?

Comment: The only solution I can think of is caching my custom styles in `beforeTextChanged()` and applying them in `afterTextChanged()` but I'm not sure if it's really possible to do it like that because by doing it like that I'd have to make the assumption that those callbacks are always called in a fixed order, i.e. first `beforeTextChanged()`, then `onTextChanged()`, and then `afterTextChanged()`.I don't know if it's guaranteed to behave like that or if it's also possible that `beforeTextChanged()` is called twice and then all the other callbacks are called twice.In that case my solution won't work

Comment: These callbacks are safe. Before-on-after, the order is ALWAYS the same, if before is called twice, unless the app doesn't crash, after is called twice too

Answer (score 1):

may be you should try this

```
SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder();
int s = sb.length();
sb.append("Hello");
sb.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(0xFFCC5500), s, 
sb.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

sb.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), s, 
sb.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
sb.append("World Test");
et.setText(sb);
```

or try this after api 21

```
SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder();
StyleSpan bold = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD);
sb.append("Hello")
          .append("BOLD ", bold, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
          .append("World");
```

like html style try below

```
String str = "<b>" + "hello" + "</b> " + "World Test"; 
et.setText(Html.fromHtml(str));
```

Comment: Tried both of your snippets but they show the very same behaviour: when positioning the cursor directly before the space character and entering a character, the text to the left of the cursor loses all of its formatting.